# Using Firestore and algolia error projectId must be a string in FirebaseApp.options

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I've been following a tutorial here https://medium.com/@soares.rfarias/how-to-index-firestore-data-into-algolia-using-cloud-functions-9ed5b56baa57 on how to link google firestore with algolia search service and although I've got through most the steps, (I was a little stuck at running the indexing script but im now past that) I'm stuck on migrating all collections from A to B I get an error that means almost nothing to me as I'm unaware of any firestore project id and i definitely dont interact directly with the folder the error points at, here is the entire error

```
C:\Users\marti\Desktop\sealstudios\functions\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\cjs\src\api\database.js:211
        throw new error_1.FirestoreError(error_1.Code.INVALID_ARGUMENT, 'projectId must be a string in FirebaseApp.options');
        ^

FirebaseError: projectId must be a string in FirebaseApp.options
at new FirestoreError (C:\Users\marti\Desktop\sealstudios\functions\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\cjs\src\util\error.js:142:28)
at Function.Firestore.databaseIdFromApp (C:\Users\marti\Desktop\sealstudios\functions\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\cjs\src\api\database.js:211:19)
at new Firestore (C:\Users\marti\Desktop\sealstudios\functions\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\cjs\src\api\database.js:110:43)
at Object.firestore (C:\Users\marti\Desktop\sealstudios\functions\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\cjs\src\platform\config.js:44:76)
at FirebaseAppImpl._getService (C:\Users\marti\Desktop\sealstudios\functions\node_modules\@firebase\app\dist\cjs\src\firebaseApp.js:117:66)
at FirebaseAppImpl.(anonymous function) [as firestore] (C:\Users\marti\Desktop\sealstudios\functions\node_modules\@firebase\app\dist\cjs\src\firebaseApp.js:304:31)
at Object.serviceNamespace [as firestore] (C:\Users\marti\Desktop\sealstudios\functions\node_modules\@firebase\app\dist\cjs\src\firebaseApp.js:289:32)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\marti\Desktop\sealstudios\functions\indexing.js:12:21)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
```

any help appreciated

Comment: Can you share your `FirebaseApp.options` and the function call to Firebase to which you pass this object?

Comment: FirebaseApp.options is system generated

Comment: What do you mean by "system-generated"? Where did you enter your firebase credentials?

Comment: It's ok I fixed it and will add an answer soon, what I meant was that file FirebaseApp.options is created by the system and not something I could edit

Comment: @martinseal1987 I'm very curious how you fix this. Could you provide an answer?

Comment: I specified it explicitly in a file I created and referenced that file in the script I'll be a little more detailed later

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be in the firebase settings. After deploing my hosting application, I deleted the settings in config / firebase.js and then found the same error on the local 8080 server.

My settings now:

```
export default {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  }
```

Check your connection settings =)

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem, When, I deploy my code on Heroku. But, that is resolved by adding environment variables on Heroku. Because, All the details for the place holders should be strings except the database URL.

So, If you have setup your variable on local in .env, you have to add the environment variables on that server where are you deploying.